# What is the best way for me to search this Product database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, permutation

I work for an e-commerce company and we recently launched a new website.  I am in charge of creating the search algorithm.

We are using a SQL Server database. We are using 'tags' to associate products with certain product keywords. I don't want to use any of our actual information so I'll replace what the data actually is with other names.

There is a `Product` table, a `Tags` table, and a `ProductTags` table that associates a product with a tag. A `Tag` can have many products and vice versa.

`Tag` table has:

```
int TagId
varchar TagName
```

`Product` table has:

```
Name
ProductId
Price
```

`ProductTags` has:

```
TagId
ProductId
TagName
ProductName
```

Right now I am splitting a search query on the spaces in the query and finding all of the 'Tags' applicable for each string.

An example query would look like: 'Red fish M60'.

I get a list of Tags from each string in the query after splitting on the spaces in the query. 
The below are all 'Tag's.

The string Red returns:

```
[Red]
```

Fish would return :

```
[Fish_Male]
[Fish_Female]
[Fish_North_America]
```

and M60 returns:

```
[M60_connection]
[M60_secure]
```

and the top hits for that search may be some products with names like

```
'Red Male Fish Secure'
'Red Female Fish Secure'
'Red Male fish North america connection'
```

and then below those would be less relevant products like

```
'red male fish farmed'
'black female fish secure'
```

and then below that would be less relevant results that only match one tag like

```
'red crab'
```

or

```
'black male fish'
```

I hope that helps.

So my question is, what is the best way (fastest, most efficient?) for me to go through these tags and return the most relevant products at the top, while not missing any products as well.

Is it feasible for me to take every possible permutation of these Tags and return the products for each permutation? (seems like a lot) As well as returning products for *each individual* Tag, like at the end.

For example, products that match three 'Tags' would be at the top of the search results, while products only matching one 'Tag' would be at the bottom. The user would be able to search any n number of Tags, as there are quite a few available. What I put down was just a quick example. Let me know if something doesn't make sense.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How is the relevence of a product determined?

Comment: We are using SQL Server.  Im not sure what you mean Dan.

Comment: Your question states that you want the most relevent products at the top.  Hence my question.

Comment: Oh I see.  The most relevant products would be the products with the most tag hits.

I edited my original, hopefully its a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a start. But I don't know if matching only on the count of tag hits is sufficient for your sorting.

```
select p.ProductId, count(*) as Relevance
from Product as p inner join ProductTags as pt on pt.ProductId = p.ProductId
where pt.TagId in (
    select TagId from Tags where TagName in (...)
)
group by p.ProductId
order by Relevance desc
```

BTW, putting ProductName and TagName in the ProductTags table is not normalized.

Comment: Yes I think as far as sorting goes that would be fine.  The products with the most tag hits would be at the top of the search results.

Comment: Note that he'd like to be able to search by tag prefixes too.That means that doing it this way, you'd need to do `LIKE "...%" OR LIKE "...%" ...` which would be inefficient.

Comment: Thanks Shawn I think this will do the trick. i just need to be able to convert this query to Linq

Comment: @dragoste I don't see that in the question anywhere. But I can't see how that's particularly inefficient of itself.

Comment: Well dragoste is correct, im searching the Tag objects that contain the strings in the TagName column.  But I'm doing that in code currently and already getting all the tag objects.  Now I just have to loop through all of them and get the different combinations of tags (permutations?)

Comment: Also ty shawn I understand that is not up to DB standards but I didn't create the design. I will have to discuss that with my superiors. Do you use Linq shawn?

Comment: @shawnt00 "Fish would return :[Fish_Male][Fish_Female][Fish_North_America]" -> [...] are tags.

Comment: Looks like you're correct. It wasn't clear to me whether those were tags or product names in the first draft of the question.

Comment: My LINQ is quite rusty but I'm pretty sure that's straightforward to translate.

Comment: im struggling converting the where clause of this query to linq

Comment: Something like this I believe: `where TagIdList.Contains(pt.TagId)`

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I have this

      'var productsForList2 = (from pt in      db.vEUProductTags
                                           where toList.Contains(pt.TagId)
                                            select pt).ToList(); 

 ' 

where "ToList" is my list of tags, but I want to be able to say where the count of relevance is equal to the number of tags in the list. Can you help me do that?