# I'm having trouble with a Linq join/groupby/orderby query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, join

I have some sort of syntax error.

```
var productsForList = from p in db.vEUProducts
                      join pt in db.vEUProductTags on p.ProductId equals pt.ProductId
                      group p by p.ProductId into relevance
                      where toList.Contains(pt.TagId) && (relevance.Count() == toList.Count)
                      orderby relevance descending
                      select pt;
```

I'm getting the error:

> **'The name "pt" does not exist in the current context"**

Why?

It's pointing to `toList.Contains(**pt**.TagId)`

All I did was add the group by and now it cannot find `pt`?

What am I missing?

TagID is a primary key.  I  have Products and I have Tags. I want to get the products that match the Tags in the list a certain number of times.

My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946812/what-is-the-best-way-for-me-to-search-this-product-database) from yesterday may help.

Comment: I think that the where condition should go before the group by

Comment: @SimoneRiboldi It can not because it uses the results of the group by.

Comment: Because after the `group` you have groups with key `ProductId` and elements of type `p`. What do you want to obtain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
var productsForList = from p in db.vEUProducts
                      join pt in db.vEUProductTags on p.ProductId equals pt.ProductId
                      where toList.Contains(pt.TagId) 
                      group pt by pt.ProductId into relevance
                      where relevance.Count() == toList.Count
                      select relevance;
```

(I've splitted the `where` in two `where`)

But I'm not sure what you are trying to do... I don't know if `TagId` is a primary key or not. You should try explaining what is `TagId` and what do you want to obtain.

Example of use of the result:

```
// Each obj is a group with key the ProductId and elements the tags matched
foreach (var obj in productsForList)
{
    int productId = obj.Key;

    foreach (var matchedTags in obj)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: TagID is a primary key.  I  have Products and I have Tags. I want to get the products that match the Tags in the list a certain number of times. 

My question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946812/what-is-the-best-way-for-me-to-search-this-product-database) from yesterday may help to clarify.

Comment: I think this would work  but it still says does not exist in the current context on the last line

Comment: @user1977591 What do you want to have, a list of vEUProductTags or a list of vEUProducts?

Comment: well it would be easier for me to get the vEUProductTags but if I could only get the ID's of the vEUProducts that would work too.  Actually either would be fine

Comment: Now you get both :-) I return groups with key ProductId and elements  vEUProductTags

Comment: I got an error when debugging.

base = {"A grouping cannot be used as an order criterion; you may want to use its key instead."}

Comment: @user1977591 How do you want to order the elements?

Comment: It doesnt matter as long as I only get the ones that have the relevance equal to the 'toList' count

Comment: @user1977591 Removed the orderby :)

Comment: Awesome :)  but I want to select the product Id's not the relevance. it is getting back enumeration yielded no results

Comment: @user1977591 Look at the example of use

Comment: This works thank you. I just wish it could be done a little cleaner. Linq is tough

Comment: @user1977591 As written you can probably remove the `from p in db.vEUProducts` and change the join to a `from pt in db.vEUProductTags`. This will remove a row :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72682/discussion-between-user1977591-and-xanatos).